# Python is there a way to hide a programm

Tags: python

```
program, info = input ("->") .split ()


if program == 'search':
   print (info)
elif program == 'hello':
   print ("do")
else:
   print ("Error")
```

In this example, the input is split.

E.g.

```
search youtube.com
```

Output:

```
youtube.com
```

But now I would also like to manage that you can only enter 1 word and it still works.

Such as.

```
elif program == 'hello':
```

that means I only type in hello and it works too.

then the output should be:

```
do
```

but only one word doesn't work at the moment, how do I get that?

Comment: Of course it won't work because you are assuming  that `input ("->") .split ()` is always going to be of length >= 2.

Comment: I don't understand the title.  What does "hide a program(m)" mean?

Answer (score 3):

You could add an asterisk to the info variable:

```py
program, *info = input("->").split()

if program == 'search':
   print(info[0])
elif program == 'hello':
   print("do")
else:
   print("Error")
```

This result in info being a list of everything after the first element of the split input. If you enter `search youtube.com`, the variable info will contain `['youtube.com']`. If you enter `hello`, the variable info will contain nothing, i.e. `[]`.

Note that I also added a list access to the info variable in line 4, where it is printed.

More information on how to solve this and/or why this works can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957771/default-value-in-python-unpacking), where default values in unpacking are discussed.

**Edit:** As @Steve pointed out, this becomes problematic if only `search` is entered, because you'd try to access the first element of an empty list. To prevent this, you can add an extra check to your code:

```py
program, *info = input("->").split()

if program == 'search':
   if not info:
      print("Error, nothing to search for")
   else:
      print(info[0])
elif program == 'hello':
   print("do")
else:
   print("Error")
```

Comment: This blows up if the user enters just "search".

Comment: @Steve Why shouldn't it? Semantically, searching for nothing is invalid.

Comment: @Steve that is correct, but I still feel like it solves OPs problem of unpacking one value into two variables. I'm still going to edit my answer now to add that.

Comment: Why should it?  My belief is that unless otherwise stated, a program should properly deal with any possible user input without throwing an exception that at least looks like a case that the programmer missed.  Are you saying that is by your own design?

Comment: Yes, it should, and no, it wasn't. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the size of the input before assigning the variables:

```
data = input("->").split()
if len(data) == 2:
    program = data[0]
    info = data[1]
elif len(data) == 1:
    program = data[0]
else:
    print("invalid number of arguments")
```

Comment: Downvoter: care to explain? what's wrong with this answer, how would you improve it?

Comment: This does nothing if three or more words are entered.  I don't know what the right behavior is.  Maybe that's it.  I just wanted to point out that that case isn't explicitly dealt with.

Comment: @Steve the question doesn't mention it explicitly, but anyway I'll add an error message for that case